# Atualizar tabela após pagamento concluído PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Bom estou tentando automatizar a liberação de produtos na minha loja para isso fiz um sistema de status de compra só que não atualiza a linha que foi paga ou seja cria uma nova linha

Veja: http://prntscr.com/febasn

Só que não sei como atualiza uma linha especifica...

Código que pega os dados: https://hastebin.com/fadiyecune.xml

[TENTATIVA] Código que atualiza o SQL:

> Aviso: Sou iniciante em PHP então fiquei meio perdido...

`$status = $_GET["status"];`

$usernick = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM compras WHERE item_token='".$_SESSION['token']."'"; // WHERE = "Condição -> 'se,onde' "   -> Nesse caso, será feita uma pesquisa na tabela loja_itens para pegar os dados de um determinado item
$result= @mysql_query("$query"); // inicia a pesquisa
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //while re-organiza todos os componentes dessa tabela, como ID, NOME, EMAIL e outros ARGUMENTOS, onde ROW = fileiras
$get_id = stripslashes($row['id']); // Nesse caso, defini a fileira dos NOME para o nome do item e pegeui seu respectivo valor.

$query26 = "UPDATE cadastro SET status='$status' WHERE id='$get_id'"; //Define uma variável para inserir na tabela os DADOS. OBS: não precisa colocar o ID, pq vc definiu como AI(Auto Increment)
mysql_query($query26); //Insere os valores definido em $query26

}

Comment: Sua query está errada não? Utilize `UPDATE compras SET status='$staus', item_nome='$item_nome' where "Seu where"`

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou

Comment: Que erro apareceu?